# Integrate PHP, JasperReports, and Apache Tomcat 6

Tags: php, tomcat, jasper-reports, php-java-bridge

I cannot make PHP & JasperReports work on Tomcat 6.

I have xampp (apache, php5.3.1, mysql, tomcat6) on Windows XP.

I followed the steps to install the php-java bridge, but PHP pages throw error.

Does someone have successfully integrate php, php-java bridge, JasperReports?

Can this be done without Apache Tomcat?

Comment: Post the exceptions now because this post will be buried under 2,000 others by the morning.

Answer (score 2):

### Background

PHP and Java are different programming languages. They require the PHP/Java Bridge to connect.

[Apache Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/) and JasperReports are Java-based technologies. They connect naturally.

[Apache HTTP Server](http://httpd.apache.org/), on the other hand, has a PHP integration.

### Architectures

#### PHP

If you have a PHP infrastructure, then the easiest solution is the following:

1. Install Apache HTTP Server.
2. Install PHP.
3. Install the latest Java Runtime Environment.
4. Install the PHP/Java Bridge.
5. Run Apache, PHP, and the PHP/Java Bridge.
6. Include the PHP/Java Bridge headers in your PHP file.
7. Call the JasperReports API from PHP.
8. Execute reports.

This is a cumbersome and technically complex solution. Using Apache Tomcat instead of Apache HTTP Server will just add to the complexity because you will need a way to integrate PHP as well.

#### Java

If you can forego PHP and use straight Java, I would recommend JavaServer Pages (JSPs). The integration becomes:

1. Install the latest Java Runtime Environment.
2. Install Apache Tomcat.
3. Call the JasperReports API from JSP.
4. Execute reports.

### Diagram

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it can be done without Tomcat. You have to run JRE on background.

See [this link](http://mathewssunny.wordpress.com/2010/12/03/jasper-reports-and-php/) for further information.

Comment: Please add the content from your site to your answer. This will help to keep your answer useful if the link changes etc. You should also probably state that the link is to your own website also for disclosure purposes.