# Calling jrxml file from php for pdf generation

Tags: php, pdf, jasper-reports

i have to generate jasper reports in my php website.

I want to know what all are needed to make this work. I was told that i needed php-java bridge. But i hope that is for the sole purpose of generating a .jrxml file.

I already have the jrxml file with me.
Now how can i call this file from my php code, for generating jasper report in pdf format ?

Comment: any sample code is appreciated.

Comment: See the following answers: - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4082775/integrate-php-jasperreports-and-apache-tomcat-6 - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5305020/pass-parameters-from-php-to-jasperreports - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5553525/passing-array-data-from-php-to-jasperreports-with-php-javabridge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, i could get what i wanted by using [PHP Jasper XML](http://www.simit.com.my/?q=node/14). It is opensource too.

Answer (score 2):

In case this file is located on your server you can open it using file_open from any php script.

EDIT: The easiest way to do it seems to be using something like the [php-jasper-integration](http://code.google.com/p/php-jasper-integration/). This way you don't need to use a java-php bridge.

---

In case you do not have it onyour server but client side only you will need to upload it to your web site and treat this file as you need to using your website script.

Here is some example code to do it:

```
if(!isset($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'])){

    // starte Session
    //session_start(); // Headers sent out

?>

<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="myscript.php" method="POST">
    <!-- MAX_FILE_SIZE must precede the file input field -->
    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="500000" />
    <!-- Name of input element determines name in $_FILES array -->
    Please upload a file.
    <br>
    <br>
    <input name="userfile" type="file" />
    <input type="submit" value="UPLOAD" />
</form>

<?php   

}
else {

?>
if ($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'] == '') die ('No file submitted!');

$target = "uploaded/"; 
$target = $target . basename( $_FILES['userfile']['name']) ; 
$ok=1; 
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $target)) 
{
    echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['userfile']['name']). " has been uploaded. Parsing will start soon. ";
} 
else {
    echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file.<br>";
}

   // now do what you need with your file in $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']
```

Comment: @Thariama sorry, but probably you are not clear about my point. I have edited my question. I have the jrxml file on my server. Why i want to call it and use in my php code is for the purpose of generating a pdf document.

Comment: so i assume you want to generate a pdf when a user navigates on a special page of your website or pushed a button, right?

Comment: Yes, that pdf must be generated using jrxml file.

Comment: @Thariama thanks... i am now searching for a code to generate pdf file using jrxml file in php...

Comment: php-jasper-integration/ offers a function to generate a php, but i do not know what software components are additionally needed

Answer (score 0):

Well jrxml is created with ireports and its executed with java, you need a server like tomcat. look for information of jru-php it will help you

Comment: please provide more information. this - in its current form - is not a complete solution.